# Undefined offset in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I usually write my for loops like so:

```
for ($i=0; $list[$i]; $i++)
```

But today I started getting the warning:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 5`

The array is 5 elements long so I know why I'm getting it, but what's weird is I've never gotten an error by writing loops like this before. Even on this server (or I thought).

I know how to fix it, by doing

```
$ct = count($list);
for ($i=0; $i < $ct; $i++)
```

but that's not the point; I want to know why it's happening.

Have my previous servers all had error reporting turned off, and this one has it on and I just never noticed it before?

I've been writing `for` loops like this for many years, so it seems like something I would have noticed. Was it a recent update in PHP?

Comment: I probably guess all other servers had error reporting off (Which is normal when your server isn't in staging).And the second code block is how you do it properly or use a foreach loop!

Comment: You should use `foreach` instead.

Comment: You should not use this. If `$list[$i]` contains a boolean `false` value, the loop will stop even if there are more items.

Comment: It is so strange why people like to do something so hard. This is absolutely data dependent loop

Comment: I'm aware of these drawbacks and wouldn't use this if any of them applied.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you array can contain out of sequence keys or even not numeric keys, for example, `array(0 => 'a', 2 => 'b')` doesn't have `1` offset, so when you try to iterate through it with `for` loop it will look for `1` offset on the second iteration (*`$i = 1`*) thus causing the notice (*it will never reach for `2` offset in this situation – yet another drawback*).

Secondly, `$list[$i]` can contain `null`, `false`, `0`, `0.0`, `"0"`, `'0'`, `''`, `""` or `array()`, thus evaluating to `false` and causing breaking from the loop (*it won't raise a notice though, but represents why this approach is bad*).

You should either use `foreach` loop instead of `for` or reindex your array with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php) (*actually it will return a new one*) before looping through it with `for` loop.

Comment: I don't think it's out of sequence keys, but that is a good point.

Comment: @felwithe: the bottomline line is: you don't have the key that  `for` loop is providing in your array . Either your notices were turned off before  or you were just lucky (let's agree it's probably the first ), but it's a bad practice anyway.

Comment: It's common to do in Perl; at the end of the day, I'm just trying to check if an array index exists. I guess notices were turned off because errors definitely weren't, for the 12+ I've been using this. That's why I thought it must have been a recent change, but I guess it was a very long string of coincidences that led to my never encountering this notice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error, but I noticed that some key/index (variable from the loop) was not existing in the array.

I solved it by checking if the key/index provided from the loop exists in the array.
I used this function `array_key_exists(array_key, array_name)` [check here](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_key_exists.php) and it worked for me.
This is mostly done if you don't need to reindex your array.

E.g.

```
for($i = 0;$i <$max; $i++) {
     if(array_key_exists($i, $array_name)){
        // if exists do something....
    }else{
      // if not exists
    }
}
```